# Impacts on refreshing access tokens frequently

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

On my .NET Web API 2 server, I am using OWIN for authentication. I have followed [Taiseer's tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) and successfully implemented an access token refresh mechanism.

I would like to know if there are any impacts on anything if clients refresh their access tokens frequently, e.g. refresh once every 5 minutes on average.

I am asking this question because I have a button on my page, when user clicks it, the data on that page is sent to different endpoints. These endpoints are marked with the attribute `[Authorize]`.

Previously, when I send a request to a single protected endpoint, I can check if the response is `401 (unauthorized)`. If so, I can refresh the user's access token first, then resend the rejected request with the new token. However, I don't know how can the same thing be done this time, as there are so many requests being sent at once. The aforementioned method is implemented in my AngularJS interceptor. It can handle a single but not multiple rejected unauthorized requests.

FYI, here is the code for my interceptor, which is found and modified from [a source on GitHub](https://github.com/Excolo/AngularJSAuthentication).

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function($q, $injector, $location, localStorageService) {
    var authInterceptor = {};
    var $http;

    var request = function(config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        var jsonData = localStorageService.get('AuthorizationData');
        if (jsonData) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + jsonData.token;
        }

        return config;
    }

    var responseError = function(rejection) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (rejection.status === 401) {
            var authService = $injector.get('authService');

            authService.refreshToken().then(function(response) {
                _retryHttpRequest(rejection.config, deferred);
            }, function() {
                authService.logout();
                $location.path('/login');
                deferred.reject(rejection);
            });
        } else {
            deferred.reject(rejection);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    var _retryHttpRequest = function(config, deferred) {
        $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
        $http(config).then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
        });
    }

    authInterceptor.request = request;
    authInterceptor.responseError = responseError;

    return authInterceptor;
});
```

Comment: In general, handing refresh tokens in the user agent is not a good idea. There is a reason for which OAuth2 defines the implicit grant (which does not issue refresh tokens) as the flow that should be used for user agent apps. ADAL JS, a library that helps to invoke web APIs from SPA applications, relies on OpenId Connect's session management. That puts the authority in charge of the session's lifetime & allows renewing of the access token without refresh tokens. If you are interested in knowing more, see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Since I am new to the field of authentication and there is already a server running this mechanism, maybe I will stick to this method for awhile before advancing to the next step. Just wondering if there are any other problems besides the one you mentioned.

Comment: Even I am concern about the same, but not getting any help